# Sending emails with SendGrid from a logic app to multiple recipients

Tags: azure-devops, azure-logic-apps, sendgrid

Is there a simple way to send emails from an Azure logic app using SendGrid to multiple recipients, e.g. comma-separated etc?

This is how it looks now:

```
       "actions": {
        "Send_email_(V3)": {
          "type": "ApiConnection",
          "inputs": {
            "host": {
              "connection": {
                "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sendgrid']['connectionId']"
              }
            },
            "method": "post",
            "body": {
              "from": "webserver@hotmail.com",
              "to": "firstaddress@somemail.com",
              "subject": "** My subject **",
              "text": "Some text",
              "ishtml": ""
            },
            "path": "/v3/mail/send"
          },
```

Is it possible to have

```
"to": "firstaddress@somemail.com, secondaddress@somemail.com"
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SendGrid V3 connector documentation states that you can separate the email addresses by comma in the `To`, `CC` or `BCC` fields:

> Valid email addresses separated by a semicolon or comma

Checkout the documentation: [SendGrid Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sendgrid/#send-email-(v3)-%5Bdeprecated%5D)

Comment: Thank you very much!